# Getting 401 (Unauthorized) error in Active Directory user image in Multi tenant Application

Tags: c#, angular, active-directory, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I have implemented Multi tenant application using Azure Active Directory in Angular 4.After user logged into my application i'm able get user info.But user photo is not getting from the Active directory for that i have implemented Graph API  like below snippet.

```
public Task<UserDto> getPhoto(TenantDto tenantDto)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(String.Format("https://graph.windows.net/{0}/users/{1}/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6", tenantDto.tenantKey, tenantDto.email));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/jpeg"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tenantDto.token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return null;
            //Status status = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Status>().Result;
            //if (status.Code == 200)
            //    InBoundResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InBoundCallResponse>(status.Data.ToString());
            //return InBoundResponse;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here `tenantDto.token` is nothing but a logged in user "token" While calling this Graph API i'm getting `401 (Unauthorized)` error. I have tried all but no use.
I have changed Graph API setting s in Active Directory APP also like below attachment 
[image]

Also i have tried like below code it's working only for single tenant

```
    [Route("AdUserImage"), HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> userImage()
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/sampletest.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token");
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);
        ActiveDirectoryClient directoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () =>
        {
            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net/", credential);
            return result.AccessToken;
        });

        var user = await directoryClient.Users.Where(x => x.UserPrincipalName == "balu@sampletest.onmicrosoft.com").ExecuteSingleAsync();
        DataServiceStreamResponse photo = await user.ThumbnailPhoto.DownloadAsync();
        using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
        {
            photo.Stream.CopyTo(s);
            var encodedImage = Convert.ToBase64String(s.ToArray());
        }
        //string token = await HttpAppAuthenticationAsync();
        Status status = new Status("OK");
        status = new Status("Found", null, "User exists.");

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, status, _jsonMediaTypeFormatter);
    }
```

but i need to implement for  Multi tenant app.

Any Answer Appreciated.

Thanks in Advance........!

Comment: There are several different `401` error(refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-error-codes-and-error-handling)) What's the detailed error message about `401`?

Comment: {
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Access Token missing or malformed."
        },
        "date": "2017-10-11T07:02:15",
        "requestId": "4f112369-931d-4a24-8f61-e303b0acb9c1",
        "values": null
    }
}    Error message while calling Graph API but token is valid because after user logged into my application directly i have calling Graph API.Thanks

Comment: Which flow you were acquiring for the access token, delegate token or application token?

Comment: I used the token which i get after user logged in successfully in my Multi tenant application

Comment: Did you use the same function as the code in the second piece of code? If I understand correctly, in this scenario, you should using the delegate token for sign-in user instead using the **client credentials flow**. And it only require `User.Read` scope, please refer [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes) about detailed scope.

Comment: The **client credentials flow** normally used for the demon application which was not able to acquire the token interactively. Refer [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service). However about the error Authentication_MissingOrMalformed, please check the token is correct for Azure AD Graph REST. I will post a code sample to get the thumbnailPhoto both using delegate-user token and application token.

Comment: I'm using Delegate-user token flow

Answer (score 1):

**Delegate-user token:**

1 .Acquire the token via the implict flow:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net&nonce={nonce}
```

2 .Call the Azure AD Graph

```
GET: https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/me/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

**Application token:**

1 .Acquire the token via the client credentials flow

```
POST:https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net
```

2 .Call the Azure AD Graph

```
GET:https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users/{upn}/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

If you only to get the thumbnail photo of sign-in user for the multiple tenant, you should login-in with Azure AD first and acquire the access token for the delegate user and used that token to call Azure AD Graph REST. Difference between these two kinds of token, you can refer the links below:

[Get access on behalf of a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user)

[Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)

Comment: I'm not able get token for Delegate-user token and also for Application token

Comment: The application token is usually used for the single tenant which the apps register on.  If you want to acquire the access token use the app for other tenant, the admin of that tenant should grant the permission(`Directory.Read.All` required admin privilege) before the app can get the access token successfully. After that you also need to get the tenant info from your sign-in user and modify it in the request, after that it should also works well. Please share the token how you acquired if you still have the problem.

Comment: @BalarajuPolaki Do you still have the problem about this issue? Please feel free to let me know if there is any step block you.

Comment: yes @ Fei Xue still i'm facing same issue.Thank you

Comment: If the issue you mean in the second post, as I mentioned that code is not suitable to run on the server-side since you will never get the UI to login. For a simple test, you can copy that URL in the browser and test that token.  Let me know if you have any problem for this test.

Comment: can you post the sample code to get User image, if it is possible than send me the link that you have done on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Delegate-user token** as per your explnation using below url
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net&nonce={nonce}`

But still not able receiving but i'm able getting 200 status but token is not return.i have implemented like below

```
                var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={ClientID}&redirect_uri={ApplicationUrl}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net&nonce=a9d7730c-79f3-4092-803a-07f346de2cdf");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                //return null;
            }
```

It's not return the token.it is returning html content  in success block

Comment: The HTTP request below is not suitable using the HttpClient to send since it requires user interactive. It only demonstrate to acquire the token for the specific request. You can copy the exact URL in the browser and after that you will be required to input the username and password. Then the token will be returned in the URL. In your scenario, you should be able to access token after user sign-in and call the Azure AD graph REST.